# Make image clickable in different regions Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, draw

I have a swing app that display a music keyboard. I'm trying to figure out how can I split the image into different regions and make each key clickable so I can play the expected note on click.

Comment: The easiest way is to just place invisible components on top of the image.

Comment: Check out http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html